# Cannot deploy Dynamic Web Module to Glassfish server

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, facelets, glassfish-4

I've been having trouble for the last few hours trying to deploy a Dynamic Web Module project to 2 different Glassfish 4 servers, one installed locally and one hosted online.

The project was working great (pom.xml & web.xml both taken from previous projects - no problems on these) even with webpages added, until I added EJB annotations for a DAO in only ONE class. Here is the class in question :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import be.helha.groupeA3.entities.Nouvelle;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class DAONouvelle {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="groupeA3JTA")
    private EntityManager em;

    public DAONouvelle() {}

    public List<Nouvelle> getAllNouvelles() {
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT n FROM Nouvelle n");
        return new ArrayList<Nouvelle>(q.getResultList());
    }

    public Nouvelle getNouvelle(Nouvelle n) {
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT n FROM Nouvelle n WHERE id=:id");
        q.setParameter("id", n.getId());
        return (Nouvelle) q.getSingleResult();
    }

    public Nouvelle createNouvelle(Nouvelle n) {
        em.persist(n);
        return n;
    }

    public int deleteNouvelle(Nouvelle n) {
        Query q = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Nouvelle n WHERE n.id=:id");
        q.setParameter("id", n.getId());
        return q.executeUpdate();
    }

    public int updateNouvelle(Nouvelle n1, Nouvelle n2) {
        Query q = em.createQuery("UPDATE Nouvelle n SET n.titre=:titre,n.description=:description,n.image=:image WHERE n.id=:id");
        q.setParameter("id", n1.getId());
        q.setParameter("titre", n2.getTitre());
        q.setParameter("description", n2.getDescription());
        q.setParameter("image", n2.getImage());
        return q.executeUpdate();

    }
}
```

I know the update and delete statements may be wrong but that's not the point.
When deploying this project to Glassfish 4, it complains about not being able to deploy the project:

```
2018-01-17T09:45:29.685+0100|Grave: Exception while preparing the app
2018-01-17T09:45:29.685+0100|Grave: Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load the EJB module. DeploymentContext does not contain any EJB. Check the archive to ensure correct packaging for C:\payara41\glassfish\domains\domain1\eclipseApps\groupeA3.
If you use EJB component annotations to define the EJB, and an ejb or web deployment descriptor is also used, please make sure that the deployment descriptor references a Java EE 5 or higher version schema, and that the metadata-complete attribute is not set to true, so the component annotations can be processed as expected
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.prepare(EjbDeployer.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:926)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:435)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:220)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:488)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:570)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:562)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:561)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1851)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1727)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:480)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've googled the stacktrace with no luck, checked my web.xml versions (3.1, worked on another project). Here is the web.xml fyi :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>groupeA3</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The persistence.xml is present in the META-INF folder as well, worked on another project (using JTA).

Now, by running a maven clean compile package, it works just fine and I can deploy it correctly to the remote glassfish 4 server, so something must be out of sync between Eclipse and Maven.

It's really hard to debug in these conditions, could you guide me on how to resolve this issue ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As far is I know eclipse has its own java compiler which is different to the standard java compiler which Maven uses when you execute Maven on the commandline.

So I would suggest to check your project setting and compare it to your command line java environment.

You can type `mvn -v` to get the java home and version information used by Maven which looks this:

```
Apache Maven 3.5.0 
Maven home: c:\Dev\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_141, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre
Default locale: de_CH, platform encoding: Cp1252
```

In Eclipse you can compare this information your project settings.